# Weighted counts in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there any way in numpy to vectorize the following operations?

```py
a = np.zeros(3)
idx = np.array([1, 0, 1])
val = np.array([1, 2, 3])
for i, v in zip(idx, val):
    a[i] += v
# a = [2, 4, 0]
```

The following code does not work as desired

```py
a = np.zeros(3)
idx = np.array([1, 0, 1])
val = np.array([1, 2, 3])
a[idx] += val
# wrong answer: a = [2, 3, 0]
```

Comment: The issue lies in the duplicate index for sure, I'm a bit surprised to see this fail to do the obvious though.

Comment: Yeah, it can be easily overlooked in practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [`np.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) setting `val` as weights:

```
np.bincount(idx, weights=val, minlength=len(idx)).astype(int)
#array([2, 4, 0])
```

---

This is in fact doing exactly as shared in the question. By adding a `weight` to `np.bincount`, instead of:

```
np.bincount(idx, minlength=len(idx)) 
# array([1, 2, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Which would be the same as obtaining the counts:

```
for i in idx:
    a[i] += 1

print(a)
# array([1., 2., 0.])
```

We have that `out[n] += weight[i]`:

```
for i, v in zip(idx, val):
    a[i] += v

print(a)
# array([2., 4., 0.])
```

Comment: If you want to retain integers, add `.astype(int)`.

Comment: do you mean `meanlength=len(a)`?

Comment: True @jan the returned values are floats with weights

Comment: So the result of bincount is `a` IIUC, you just need to set it to the length of the values you're iterating over (the iterables in `zip`) @quang

Comment: Hi, @yatu thanks for the answer. Could you please think of a way to get the desired `idx` and `val` elegantly as I added to the question?

Comment: Don't you want to obtain `a`? The question seems a bit confusing then, since you start with `Is there any way in numpy to vectorize the following operations?`, where you hardcode `idx` and `val`, and calculate `a` @maybe

Comment: The question seems in fact two fold, first you're asking to vectorize something (which is answered here), and then after `In fact, I want to get the desired...` you ask a different question @maybe

Comment: Yeah, the first part is in fact I wanted to ask in the first place. But then I realized it was not enough...Maybe I have to ask another question.

Comment: Your question needs to be a little more focused @maybe its confusing. I'd suggest leave the first part of the question, and perhaps ask the last part separately